# .NET ToolStrip control bug: leave event not fired until the ToolStrip is disposed

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, toolstrip, toolstripcontrolhost

To reproduce this bug you need to create custom `ToolStripItem`, using `ToolStripControlHost`.
In my case, I made `ToolStripDateTimePicker` control (as seen on many good tutorials). The control however behaves slightly different than a regular `DateTimePicker`.

Regular one produces default Windows bell sound when `ESC` is pressed while it's active. The `ToolStrip` hosted control reacts for `ESC` pressed in a more sensible manner. The control becomes inactive, no beep.

Here's the bug part: when focusing another control with a click - regular `DateTimePicker` triggers `Leave` event. As expected. `ToolStrip` hosted control DOES NOT trigger any event!

Yes, I've tried `KeyDown` event - it's not sent when `ESC` key is pressed, but sent when any other key is pressed.

I believe it's a bug in .NET itself.

The consequence of this is broken focus behavior of the form containing the `ToolStrip` control. The form cannot be focused again after entering `ToolStrip` hosted control.

But it's a workaround for this: you can focus an other form (or even maybe another control), and then the target form - it works for me.

However I would like to have it done automatically - the moment user exits the hosted control. The problem is I don't have an event for this. Any ideas?

What's weird, `Leave` event is eventually triggered when the hosted control is disposed - it's clearly a bug, because the event is totally useless there.

Here: [sample application illustrating the problem](http://nisza.org/so/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip)
**I've replaced it with sample workaround, to see the problem comment out `OnGotFocus()` and `OnLostFocus()` overrides.**

It worked nice (and could not reproduce the bug) until I've changed `FlowLayoutPanel` `TabIndex` to 0, so the `DateTimePicker` is not active when the application starts.

Comment: _"I believe it's a bug in .NET itself"_ - then you wouldn't have any problem creating a (very) small project that shows the erroneous behavior. Can you try to do so? From your description it sounds it should just work, how do you determine the events aren't fired?

Comment: OK, I've created a sample application. I don't have time to make it more elaborate, I'm working on this issue with real application. Deadlines... ;)

Comment: Works for me - as long as there is _another_ control on the same form. :) When there is no control to leave focus to, I think the Leave event isn't raised.

Comment: If it's a bug, then report it to Microsoft, not to Stack Overflow. When you report it, be sure to say which .NET version and OS version the problem occurs on.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure if it's a bug. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've figured out I can expose TabStop and TabIndex properties of a hosted control, but for now it does nothing. When I'm done, someone will be able to benefit from this experience. Or not ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster: there IS another control, the FlowLayoutPanel. It's empty, so it shows nothing. In my real application I have a large group of controls there.

Comment: Is there any control present with `CanFocus` returning `true`? I'm not sure about the Win32 rules for focusing, but I suspect this not to be a bug but by design. If you for example add a `TextBox` to the `FlowLayoutPanel`, the event is raised when you press Tab or click outside the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I learned:

The problem was not exactly with `ToolStripControlHost` class, but with the `DateTimePicker` control itself, and to be more specific - with it's interaction with `FlowLayoutPanel`s and possibly other similar controls. And I'm not sure if it's a bug or expected behavior, but seems more like a bug.

Here's how it works:
If there is another control which can be obviously activated (like `TextBox`), leaving the `DatePickerControl` means activating the other control. But if the other control is empty container, or **container with no controls which can be activated** - `Leave` event is not triggered despite the `DateTimePicker` control is not active anymore.

Why would you want to have a container with no active controls active itself? I use `FlowLayoutPanel` to produce a read-only, non-editable report. It is not editable, but I want it scrollable, and I don't want `DateTimePicker` control to steal focus from `FlowLayoutPanel` - so in this case `FlowLayoutPanel` **is** an active control.

Of course it doesn't work this way. There are more workarounds needed for such behavior to be achieved, like receiving mouse events from containing form, but correct `Focus`/`Leave` behavior for `ToolStripDatePickerControl` is a good start.

So without further ado, my perfect `ToolsStripDateTimePicker` control, with focus glitch fixed:

`DesignerToolStripControlHost` class:

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms {
    /// <summary>
    /// Fixes ToolStripControlHost broken designer behavior
    /// </summary>
    public class DesignerToolStripControlHost : ToolStripControlHost {
        /// <summary>
        /// Fixes designer bug by creating a constructor allowing to create ToolStripControlHost
        /// without parameter
        /// </summary>
        public DesignerToolStripControlHost() : base(new UserControl()) { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Windows.Forms.DesignerToolStripControlHost
        /// class that hosts the specified control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        public DesignerToolStripControlHost(Control c) : base(c) { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Windows.Forms.DesignerToolStripControlHost
        /// class that hosts the specified control and that has the specified name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        public DesignerToolStripControlHost(Control c, string name) : base(c, name) { }
    }
}
```

`ToolStripDateTimePicker` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace System.Windows.Controls {

    [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
    public partial class ToolStripDateTimePicker : DesignerToolStripControlHost, IComponent {

        public ToolStripDateTimePicker() : base(new DateTimePicker() { Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0), Width = 150, Value = DateTime.Now.Date }) { }

        #region Properties

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Design")]
        [Description("Internal ToolStrip hosted control.")]
        public DateTimePicker DateTimePickerControl { get { return Control as DateTimePicker; } }

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Gets or sets the tab order of the control within its container.")]
        public int TabIndex { get { return DateTimePickerControl.TabIndex; } set { DateTimePickerControl.TabIndex = value; } }

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can give the focus to this control using the TAB key.")]
        public bool TabStop { get { return DateTimePickerControl.TabStop; } set { DateTimePickerControl.TabStop = value; } }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [Description("This property is ignored.")]
        public override string Text { get { return DateTimePickerControl.Value.ToString(); } set { DateTimePickerControl.Value = DateTime.Parse(value); } }

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("The current date/time value for this control.")]
        public DateTime Value { get { return DateTimePickerControl.Value; } set { DateTimePickerControl.Value = value; } }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Focus")]
        [Description("Occurs when the input focus enters the control.")]
        public new EventHandler Enter;

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Focus")]
        [Description("Occurs when the input focus leaves the control.")]
        public new EventHandler Leave;

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Occurs when the value of the control changes.")]
        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

        protected void OnEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) { EventHandler handler = Enter; if (handler != null) handler(this, e); }

        protected void OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) { EventHandler handler = Leave; if (handler != null) handler(this, e); }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            if (Enter != null) {
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks - _FocusGlitchFix_LastEvent > _FocusGlitchFixTickWindow) Enter.Invoke(this, e);
                _FocusGlitchFix_LastEvent = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            if (Leave != null) {
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks - _FocusGlitchFix_LastEvent > _FocusGlitchFixTickWindow) Leave.Invoke(this, e);
                _FocusGlitchFix_LastEvent = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            }
        }

        protected void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { EventHandler handler = ValueChanged; if (handler != null) handler(this, e); }

        protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control control) {
            base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(control);
            DateTimePickerControl.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnValueChanged);
        }

        protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control control) {
            base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(control);
            DateTimePickerControl.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler(OnValueChanged);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Focus Glitch Workaround data

        private long _FocusGlitchFix_LastEvent = 0;
        private readonly long _FocusGlitchFixTickWindow = 100000; // 10ms

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Workarounds explained:

1. Original DTP `OnGotFocus()` and `OnLostFocus()` event handlers are overridden to trigger my new control `Enter` and `Leave` events. Note that they are triggered almost correctly.
2. When the control is the only one which can be activated, when the control is first left it's activated and deactivated instantly - which means doubled (redundant) `Enter` and `Leave` events. We don't want those, so I check the time between events, if it's smaller than 10ms I just ignore later event.
3. `DesignerToolStripControlHost` is used to fix broken designer behavior. If you used `ToolStripControlHost` directly, you would get an exception trying to show the control's designer view, because designer tries to instantiate this class with no argument, and this class does not have a constructor with no argument. So my new class does.
4. When designer view of a form containing `ToolStripDateTimePicker` break which you can tell by seeing DTP disappeared, just close designer view and open it again. It will work fine until you compile or debug your application again.

Glitch fix was tested with 1ms time window and worked fine. So I chose 10ms to ensure it works on slower or more loaded machines, but it's still short enough to capture any event from user interaction.